# How to display byte[] to the UI in string of words

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, blob, inputstream

I am taking the input of strings from the ms word and saving in database using blob and I want to now take the data from the data base and display it to the UI. please help me how to render the contents to the UI

This is my Controller to show how I'm taking the data from MS Word:

```
@RequestMapping(value="studentattedanceupload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String AttendanceUpload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam Long batchId, @RequestParam Long slotId, @RequestParam String date) {
    String langCode = "EN";
    Long moduleId = (long) 1;

    try {
        MultipartFile multipartFile = request.getFile("filename");
        byte[] bytes = multipartFile.getBytes();
        String content= multipartFile.getContentType();

        mockTestService.saveInstruction(bytes,content, langCode, moduleId);

        return "1";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error while uploading the Attendance List", e);
    }
    return "2";
}
```

This is my service layer:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)    
public void saveInstruction(byte[] bytes,String content, String langCode, Long moduleId) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ModuleDetails moduleDetails = moduleDetailsDao.getModuleDetailsByMid(moduleId);
    if(moduleDetails != null){
        LanguageDetails languageDetails = languageDetailsDao.getLanguageDetailsByLangId(langCode);
        if(languageDetails != null){

            InstructionSet instructionSet = instructionSetDao.getInstructionSetById(new InstructionSetPK(moduleDetails, languageDetails));
            if(instructionSet == null){
                instructionSet = new InstructionSet();
                instructionSet.setInstructionSetPK(new InstructionSetPK(moduleDetails, languageDetails));
                instructionSet.setInstruction(bytes);
                instructionSet.setContent(content);
                instructionSetDao.save(instructionSet);
            }else{
                instructionSet.setInstruction(bytes);
            }
        }else{
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
    }else{
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

This is my DAO:

```
@Override
public Serializable save(Object entity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return  currentSession().save(entity);
}
```

This is my models: 
`InstructionSet` model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TB_INSTRUCTION_SET")
public class InstructionSet implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private InstructionSetPK instructionSetPK;

    @Column(name="INSTRUCTION")
    @Lob
    private byte[] instruction;

    @Column(name="CONTENT")
    private String content;

    public InstructionSet() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

// getter and setter are initialised

model for `InstructionSetPk`

```
@Embeddable
public class InstructionSetPK implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="MODULE_ID")
    private ModuleDetails moduleDetails;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="LANG_ID")
    private LanguageDetails languageDetails;

    public InstructionSetPK() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

And now I want the data stored in the database to be displayed in the UI as the strings that's been entered in the Word. For that I am able to get the `byte[]`, but I want to display the contents as it was in ms word not the encrypted `byte`.

This is my service layer trying to fetch the data:

```
@Override
public InstructionSet getInstructionFromModuleIdAndLangCode(Long moduleId,
            String langCode) {
    ModuleDetails moduleDetails = moduleDetailsDao.getModuleDetailsByMid(moduleId);
    if(moduleDetails != null){
        LanguageDetails languageDetails = languageDetailsDao.getLanguageDetailsByLangId(langCode);
        if(languageDetails != null){
            InstructionSet instructionSet = instructionSetDao.getInstructionSetById(new InstructionSetPK(moduleDetails, languageDetails));
            return instructionSet;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

My Controller (**I'm stuck there**)

```
@RequestMapping(value="instructiondisplay", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void instructionDisplay(HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response/*, @RequestParam String langCode, @RequestParam Long moduleId*/){
    String langCode = "EN";
    Long moduleId = (long) 1;
    try{
        InstructionSet instructionSet=mockTestService.getInstructionFromModuleIdAndLangCode(moduleId, langCode);
        if(instructionSet!=null){
            InputStream inputStream= request.getInputStream();
            inputStream.read(instructionSet.getInstruction());
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ;    
}
```

**I am not sure how to get the data and send it to the UI.**

Comment: How about reading http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part4.html?

Comment: I am able to send the data for the UI in byte[] but all i need to send is the String... That is where i am stuck and i m not sure how to send the string using inputstream

Comment: are you looking for `new String(byte[])`? (and there should be no `InputStream` involvement)

Comment: I tried with String(byte[]) but the i am still getting some encrupted kind of data. I have sent "Hi world" from the MS word and saved it inside the database as blob type. No i want to retrive the Hi world and send it as a string to the UI rather now i m getting some byte type encupted data....

Comment: `getBytes` on a file returns the file content and MSWord is not plain text, so the file content **is not** the text content.

Comment: so how should i display it using the inputstream... and i also want to send the content type to the brower

Comment: You can **not** "display" a word document

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) here, it has been used to read docx, xls etc.

Comment: no i have the data in db and the datatype is blob. all i need is to take the data and display it with the help of inputstream. thats were i am stuck

Comment: As you have mentioned, you have input-stream available with you, create a file or fileinputstream object using that input-stream and then send this file as parameter to other objects. Kindly ignore if I am out of bounds.